# Which Scala open source projects should I study to learn best coding practices

Tags: scala

What open source projects would you recommend for people to study to learn how the pros write Scala?

Some of the attributes that I'm looking for - though they don't all have to be present in every exemplary project:

- Idiomatic use of the language and libraries
- Functional programming techniques
- Concurrency (using Actors or other methods)
- Large scale system with many modules
- Readability
- Java interop
- etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **[Akka project](http://akka.io/)** can be interesting (but quite complex): [source code](https://github.com/jboner/akka).

You can combine that reading with the [Scala Style guide](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/).

Comment: I've been looking at the Akka code recently.   It is very nice.